# Divs don't appears on main div, and div width don't work

Tags: css

Can anybody help, I`m starter in web? Here is code:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.window {
margin:0;
padding:0;
border: solid 1px #666666;
}
.image {
height:50px;
widows:50px;
float:left;
}
.text {
font-size:12px;
color:#666666;
float:left;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="window">
<div class="image">image</div>
<div class="text"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for width, u use window, use width:50px; for appear div image and div text on div window, use clear div, see code below...

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.window {
margin:0;
padding:0;
border: solid 1px #666666;
}
.image {
height:50px;
width:50px;
float:left;
}
.text {
font-size:12px;
color:#666666;
float:left;
}
.clear {
clear:both;
}   
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="window">
<div class="image">image</div>
<div class="text"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Is ok?

Answer (score 0):

Misspelt width?

> widows:50px;

Answer (score 0):

because you have `float:left` for the two child elements you have to clear them. Add `overflow:auto` for the `.window`.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/CVcjf/1

Answer (score -1):

you should assign a width and height to the divs in order to make its visible.